# How to distribute the same apk for regular and instant app

Tags: java, android, google-play, android-instant-apps

I want to distribute my app as both normal and instant app on Google Play, the size of the normal apk is below 4 mb so it can also be an instant app, the question is how do I distribute the app in both "modes" using the same apk/app bundle

Answer (score 2):

While you still can upload an instant-app-apks.zip using the deprecated model, the documentation for that has already disappeared, but you may find some remnants in this [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-instant-apps/index.html#0), and as @Hassan Ibraheem noted, your instant app will need `targetSandboxVersion=2` and your installed-app not. Then, you will build two separate artifacts, installed-app.apk and instant-app-apks.zip, and upload them into their respective releases.

However, the following is now the official way to setup your app to support instant apps while using one bundle for the regular and instant app:

Also read [Android Developers Blog: A simpler experience for instant apps](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/04/google-play-instant-feature-plugin.html)

To release the instant app and the regular app at the same time, perform the following steps:

1. [Create an instant-enabled app bundle](https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/getting-started/instant-enabled-app-bundle), please note:

> If you have an existing instant app project that uses the deprecated
>   feature plugin (com.android.feature), learn how to migrate your
>   instant app to support Android App Bundles.

2. Publish the Instant enabled bundle first on the Android Instant Apps track.

   - note: you should only need to upload the bundle here once
3. Navigate to the Installed app Releases tab.
4. A button labeled “Add from library” should be displayed on the right side of the screen to select the APK for your installed app.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the `android:targetSandboxVersion` attribute to 2 to be able to upload the APK to the instant app tracks.

This is irreversible for existing users, so make sure you read the documentation carefully and test your app before publishing with the new targetSandboxVersion: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element#targetSandboxVersion